# How to convert a data frame grid to a shapefile?

Tags: convert, arcgis-9.3

I have a map layout set up in ArcMap 9.3.1 with an index grid on the data frame.  What I would like to do is convert this index grid to a shapefile that includes the grid reference information.  I've tried the Convert Graphics to Features button on the Drawing toolbar, but it is greyed out.  Is anyone aware of a method or script to perform this operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only partially answers your question, but I've used [Hawth's Tools](http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/download.php) in the past:
http://www.spatialecology.com/htools/createvectorgrid.php.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The following procedure takes in a few paramaters that define the "extent" of the grid and the intervals. If the destination feature class (Selected in the TOC) has a field named "Label" then the coordinates are stored in this field.
Paste procedure into VBA, create your shapefile/feature class of the desired coordinate system, add to ArcMap, start editing, select the layer in the TOC and run procedure from the immediate window passing it the desired parameters. Alternatively you could create a form where you type the coordinates and intervals into text boxes for simplicity.

```
Public Sub CreateGrid(UpperLeftX As Double, UpperLeftY As Double, BottomRightX As Double, BottomRightY As Double, IntervalX As Double, IntervalY As Double)

'©Jakub Sisak, 2009

    Dim pUID As New UID
    Dim pEditor As IEditor
    Dim pEditLayers As IEditLayers
    Dim pActiveView As IActiveView
    Dim pEnumFeature As IEnumFeature
    Dim pNewFeature As IFeature

    Dim pPolyline As IPolyline5
    Dim pFromPoint As IPoint
    Dim pToPoint As IPoint
    Dim TargetFeatureClass As IFeatureClass

    Dim c As Long
    Dim incrementX As Double
    Dim incrementY As Double

    Dim labelindex As Integer


    pUID = "esriCore.Editor"
    Set pEditor = Application.FindExtensionByCLSID(pUID)
    Set pEditLayers = pEditor
    Set pActiveView = pEditor.Map

    If pEditor.EditState = esriStateNotEditing Then
        MsgBox "You be editing to use this!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If Not pEditLayers.CurrentLayer.FeatureClass.ShapeType = esriGeometryPolyline Then
        MsgBox "Destination layer must be a polyline type!"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set TargetFeatureClass = pEditLayers.CurrentLayer.FeatureClass
        labelindex = TargetFeatureClass.FindField("label")
        If labelindex = -1 Then
            If MsgBox("Label field does not exist in the target feature class." & Chr(13) & _
                    "Longitude & Latitude numeric values will not be stored!" & Chr(13) & _
                    "Continue Anyaway") = vbNo Then
                    Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    End If



    'Start an edit operation
    pEditor.StartOperation

    incrementX = UpperLeftX
    Do While incrementX < BottomRightX
        Application.StatusBar.message(0) = "Creating Latitude " & incrementX

        Set pFromPoint = New Point
        Set pToPoint = New Point
        Set pPolyline = New Polyline

        pFromPoint.x = incrementX
        pFromPoint.y = UpperLeftY
        pPolyline.FromPoint = pFromPoint

        pToPoint.x = incrementX
        pToPoint.y = BottomRightY
        pPolyline.ToPoint = pToPoint

        Set pNewFeature = pEditLayers.CurrentLayer.FeatureClass.CreateFeature
        Set pNewFeature.Shape = pPolyline
        If labelindex <> -1 Then pNewFeature.Value(labelindex) = incrementX
        pNewFeature.Store
        incrementX = (incrementX) + (IntervalX) 'negative values probably
    Loop


    incrementY = BottomRightY
    Do While incrementY < UpperLeftY
        Application.StatusBar.message(0) = "Creating Longtitude " & incrementY

        Set pFromPoint = New Point
        Set pToPoint = New Point
        Set pPolyline = New Polyline

        pFromPoint.x = UpperLeftX
        pFromPoint.y = incrementY
        pPolyline.FromPoint = pFromPoint

        pToPoint.x = BottomRightX
        pToPoint.y = incrementY
        pPolyline.ToPoint = pToPoint

        Set pNewFeature = pEditLayers.CurrentLayer.FeatureClass.CreateFeature
        Set pNewFeature.Shape = pPolyline
        If labelindex <> -1 Then pNewFeature.Value(labelindex) = incrementY
        pNewFeature.Store
        incrementY = (incrementY) + (IntervalY) 'negative values probably
    Loop


    'Complete the edit operation
    pEditor.StopOperation "Create Polylines"

    pActiveView.Refresh

End Sub
```

Comment: Forgot to mention that the script works in both versions 9 & 10.

Answer (score 3):

Check this tool out, its the best I've found.

http://arcscripts.esri.com/details.asp?dbid=15732

Comment: Please include at least the name of the tool so if/when the link changes people have a hope of finding it again. Also a good idea to add a short description. Thanks.